Number of ways a positive integer n can be expressed as a sum of k natural numbers under a certain ordering condition
I have a question that I can't solve for the moment. Suppose we have a fixed positive integer $k$, now consider $k$
natural numbers $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$
such that they satisfy the following condition:
$$
0 \leq x_1 \leq 1, \quad 0 \leq x_2 \leq 2, \quad \dots, \quad 0 \leq x_k \leq k.
\label{a}\tag{$*$}$$
I appreciate any help from you to tell me how many ways to get a fixed positive integer $n$ $(n≥k)$
such that $$n=x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k,$$
without taking order into account.
Example: there are $7$ ways to write $n=6$
when $k=4$:
\begin{align}
6&=0+0+2+4=0+2+0+4 \tag1 \\
6&=0+1+2+3=1+0+2+3=1+2+0+3=1+2+3+0 \tag2 \\
6&=1+1+2+2=1+2+1+2=1+2+2+1 \tag3 \\
6&=0+0+3+3 \tag4 \\
6&=0+1+1+4=1+0+1+4=1+1+0+4 \tag5 \\
6&=1+1+1+3=1+1+3+1 \tag6 \\
6&=0+2+2+2 \tag7
\end{align}
I read the wikipedia article about Restricted integer partitions, but how to use them considering the condition \eqref{a}?

I believe that these numbers are coefficients of the Carlitz-Riordan $q$-Catalan numbers, https://oeis.org/A227543.

Edit: See updated answer below.
You're looking for the number of partitions of $n$ that have at most $k$ parts each at most $k$.  Graphically, this is asking how many partitions of $n$ have a Ferrers diagram that fits in a $k \times k$ box.  This is given by the $q$-binomial series (see, for instance, the book Integer Partitions by Andrews and Eriksson, p70).
For your $k=4$ example,
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{m = 0}^4 q^m \left[ {4 + m - 1}\atop{m} \right]_q & =  1 + q + 2 q^2 + 3 q^3 + 5 q^4 + 5 q^5 + 7 q^6 + 7 q^7 + 8 q^8 \\
& \quad + 7 q^9 + 7 q^{10} + 5 q^{11} + 5 q^{12} + 3 q^{13} + 2 q^{14} + q^{15} + q^{16}
\end{align*}
documents all the partitions of $n$ that fit inside a $4 \times 4$ box from the empty partition of 0 to the partition $(4,4,4,4)$ of 16.  The $7q^6$ term matches the count you worked out for $n = 6$.
This also connects to the OEIS number triangle A096771 where $t(n,k)$ counts the number of partitions of $n$ that fit inside a $k \times k$ box but not a $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ box, so the count you want is the sum of the first $k$ columns.  For example, the $n = 6$ row is $(0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2)$ and $0+0+3+4 = 7$.

I misunderstood the problem (and was misled by the answer my misunderstanding gave that matched the example).  Instead of partitions that fit in a $4 \times 4$ square, for example, you want partitions that fit inside the $(4,3,2,1)$ triangle.
In addition to A227543 and A129176 mentioned in comments by Ira Gessel and Jukka Kohonen, respectively, there are (at least!) two other OEIS entries to look at.
The analogue of A096771 mentioned above is A136625 where $t(n,k)$ counts the number of partitions of $n$ that fit inside the $(k,k-1,\ldots,2,1)$ "staircase Ferrers board" but not inside $(k-1, \ldots, 2, 1)$.  The $n=6$ row is $(0,0,1,6,2,2)$ where the 1 corresponds to the partition $(3,2,1)$ and $1+6=7$ matches the 7 partitions you worked out.
The column sums of this triangle (each column has finitely many nonzero entries) is A071724 which has a nice formula and connections to other combinatorial objects.  There's a link to a helpful graphic by Gus Wiseman showing the 28 partitions (of any $n$) that fit inside $(4,3,2,1)$ but not inside $(3,2,1)$.

Thanks Brian for the effort that you made to answer my question. To be exact; I'm looking for the number of partitions of n that have at most k parts, such thst 1st part has at most 1, 2nd part has at most 2,       3rd part has at most 3,....., k_th part has at most k.

By Brian's last paragraph, these seem to be A129176, appropriately shifted.

... and in fact A129176 is said to be "Mirror image of A227543" (which in turn was already mentioned in Ira Gessel's comment).
